# PostgreSQL distinct and grouping

Tags: postgresql

Once upon a time in a table...

| segment | column |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| a | 1 |
| a | 2 |
| a | 3 |
| b | 4 |
| b | 5 |
| b | 5 |
| c | 6 |
| c | 7 |
| ... | ... |

And this is what I like to see as an end result:

| segment | sum |
| --- | --- |
| a | COUNT(DISTINCT(column) in segment a |
| b | COUNT(DISTINCT(column) in segment b |
| c | COUNT(DISTINCT(column) in segment c |
| ... | ... |

What would it be like with a for loop?
Or there is a simple, elegant way in postgreSQL?

I tried for loop but it still doesn't work :)

Comment: Wouldn't `SELECT segment, COUNT(DISTINCT column) FROM t GROUP BY segment` do what you want?

Comment: Oh holy... like a beginner :D thanks...

Comment: @Marth why not just provide an answer instead of a comment? at least questions can be identified as "done" that way...